# How do I add custom events to classes in node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, events, custom-events

So I'm just picking up node and I'm wondering how do I add custom events to a class. Code below of my attempt. Essentially just creating a simple farm class, and every time the number of animals change, I display the new number. The event I'm trying to create is totalChanged.

```
let events = require('events');

class Farm{
    constructor(totalAnimals){
        this._totalAnimals = totalAnimals;
        events.EventEmitter.call(this);
    }

    get totalAnimals(){
        return this._totalAnimals
    }

    set totalAnimals(newTotal){
        this._totalAnimals = newTotal;
    }

    sellAnimals(amount){
        this._totalAnimals -= amount;
        this.emit("totalChanged");
    }

    buyAnimals(amount){
        this._totalAnimals += amount;
        this.emit("totalChanged");
    }

    toString(){
        return "Number of animals in farm: " + this._totalAnimals;
    }
}

let testFarm = new Farm(100);
testFarm.on("totalChanged",testFarm.toString());
testFarm.buyAnimals(20);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You've got a couple options:

If you want to use `instance.on` you have to *inherit* from [`EventEmitter`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_eventemitter) like so:

```
let EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

class Farm extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  buyAnimals() {
    this.emit('totalChanged', { value: 'foo' })
  }
}

let testFarm = new Farm()
testFarm.on('totalChanged', value => {
  console.log(value)
})

testFarm.buyAnimals()
```

If you prefer to use [composition instead of inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), you can simply instantiate `EventEmitter` as a property and use `instance.eventEmitter.on` like so:

```
let EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter

class Farm {
  constructor() {
    this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter()
  }

  buyAnimals() {
    this.eventEmitter.emit('totalChanged', { value: 'foo' })
  }
}

let testFarm = new Farm()
testFarm.eventEmitter.on('totalChanged', value => {
  console.log(value)
})

testFarm.buyAnimals()
```